# Get Literal types for object keys in typescript dynamically?

Tags: typescript, generics, types, type-conversion, strong-typing

I want to get object keys type, here i write a generic for object with keys as string

```
type GenericInput = {
  [key:string]: {value:string,type:HTMLInputTypeAttribute,placeholder:string,min?:number,max?:number,required?:boolean, error?:string}
}

function PageContent(props: { children: React.ReactNode,inputs:GenericInput,getData:(data)=>void}) {
  const [query,setQuery] = useState<GenericInput>(props.inputs)
  
  const formKeys = Object.keys(query)
getData(query)
}
```

But I want to pass data such that i get object literal of key type So when that IDE provide auto-completion for keys. Kind of want to convert keys into literal type.

i want to achieve something like that,

```
 type GenericInput = {
      [key:  Object.keys(query)]:{value:string,type:HTMLInputTypeAttribute,placeholder:string,min?:number,max?:number,required?:boolean, error?:string}
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Typescript `Record` Generic Type

To Create an object interface with known keys you can use `Record`, and, to create an object interface with unknown keys you can use `[key: string]: TYPE`.

TO Work with `Record` and for you question :

```js
type GenericInputProperties = {
    value: string;
    type: HTMLInputTypeAttribute;
    placeholder: string;
    min?: number;
    max?: number;
    required?: boolean;
    error?: string;
};

type GenericInput<Keys> = Record<Keys, GenericInputProperties>;
```

refs :
[Typescript `Record`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type)
[Typescript `Generics`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html)

Enjoy :)